# What does it mean for a closed set to contain a sequence?

Tags: vector-analysis

In vector analysis the closedness of a set can be defined as

> A set A is closed, iff for each convergent sequence $x_k \in A$, the limit point $a$ of the sequence $x_k$ also belongs to A.

What does it mean for a set to contain "all convergent sequences $x_k \in A$"? Why is there the wording "for each convergent sequence $x_k \in A$"?

Can one actually list "all convergent sequences $x_k \in A$"?

Comment: The notation here is, as you point out, a bit confusing.  The statement is not that the sequence $\{x_k\}$ "belongs" to set $A$, but rather that you have a sequence whose entries $x_k$ each belong to $A$.  Requiring that the sequence be "convergent" means (as the answer below explains) that the sequence converges in the topological space containing subset $A$ (there being no notation in the snippet quoted for what this topological space is).

Answer (score 1):

It means that you consider all sequences $x_n$ that are convergent [in the underlying vector space] so that all of its elements $x_n$ lie in $A$.

For example, the set $A = (0, 1)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, because the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is convergent [in $\mathbb{R}$], but its limit $0$ isn't contained in $A$.